# Unable to boot CD

Tags: boot, windows, dvd, cd

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 and uninstalled Windows some time ago;

However, i want to re-install Windows again and burned a copy to a CD (DVD+R) using write to disc pop-up right-click menu on the .iso file.

The CD is detected by the BIOS and it is first in boot order, however, nothing happens when powering the computer.

What is the solution and what is causing this?

Comment: Can you be clearer on "nothing happens" - boots to Linux, fails to boot & chokes on the CD, fails to power-up? Have you tried a 2nd CD?

Comment: Nothing happens means that ubuntu boots like usual. I power-up PC, choose Ubuntu from its options although i have one that is allways there called Windows Recovery something... which does not work in anyway. And yes, i have tried a 2nd CD.

Comment: OK, so your PC isn't seeing the CD (or isn't successfully booting off it) - BIOS's vary here, I see you have it as 1st boot in sequence but it may still be worth trying the boot menu - often F2 or F11 when booting - and turning on all the BIOS reporting if it's not already on, to see if it even refers to the CD - you may well spot an error. Booting from CD isn't actually a function of the Ubuntu system, so this is really between the CD & your PC's BIOS...

Answer (score 0):

The right-click pop-up is almost certainly copying the .iso file to disk as a file in a filesystem, instead of actually filling the CD with it AS the filesystem.

Try using something like K3b to burn it **as an ISO image** instead.